# How to overcome overfitting in convolutional neural network when nothing helps?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm training a convolutional neural network with siamese architecture and constrastive loss function for face verification task. And I'm faced with a huge difference in training and validation accuracy starting from literally first three or five epochs. When training accuracy reaches 95% I have ~65% validation accuracy. It is fluctuating somewhere near 70% but never reaches this number.
[these are training and validation accuracy plotted on one chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrlcG.png)

So to avoid this I tried a range of standard techniques when it comes to overfitting, but before listing them here I should say that none of them really changes the picture. The gap between training and validation accuracy stays the same. So I used:

- L1 regularization with lambda varying from 0.0001 to 10000.0
- L2 regularization with lambda varying from 0.0001 to 10000.0
- Dropout with rate from 0.2 to 0.8
- Data augmentation techniques (rotation, shifting, zooming)
- Removing fully connected layers except last layer.

Nothing of these really help, so I appreciate any advises from you guys.
And some information about the network itself. I'm using tensorflow. This is how the model itself look like:

```
net = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs,
    kernel_size=(7, 7),
    filters=15,
    strides=1,
    activation=tf.nn.relu,
    kernel_initializer=w_init,
    kernel_regularizer=reg)
# 15 x 58 x 58
net = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(net, pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2)
# 15 x 29 x 29
net = tf.layers.conv2d(
    net,
    kernel_size=(6, 6),
    filters=45,
    strides=1,
    activation=tf.nn.relu,
    kernel_initializer=w_init,
    kernel_regularizer=reg)
# 45 x 24 x 24
net = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(net, pool_size=(4, 4), strides=4)
# 45 x 6 x 6
net = tf.layers.conv2d(
    net,
    kernel_size=(6, 6),
    filters=256,
    strides=1,
    activation=tf.nn.relu,
    kernel_initializer=w_init,
    kernel_regularizer=reg)
# 256 x 1 x 1
net = tf.reshape(net, [-1, 256])
net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=reg, kernel_initializer=w_init)
net = tf.layers.dropout(net, rate=0.2)
# net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=reg, kernel_initializer=w_init)
# net = tf.layers.dropout(net, rate=0.75)
return tf.layers.dense(net, units=embedding_size, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_init)
```

This is how loss function is implemented:

```
def contrastive_loss(out1, out2, labels, margin):
distance = compute_euclidian_distance_square(out1, out2)
positive_part = labels * distance
negative_part = (1 - labels) * tf.maximum(tf.square(margin) - distance, 0.0)
return tf.reduce_mean(positive_part + negative_part) / 2
```

This is how I get and augment data (I'm using LFW dataset):

```
ROTATIONS_RANGE = range(1, 25)
SHIFTS_RANGE = range(1, 18)
ZOOM_RANGE = (1.05, 1.075, 1.1, 1.125, 1.15, 1.175, 1.2, 1.225, 1.25, 1.275, 1.3, 1.325, 1.35, 1.375, 1.4)
IMG_SLICE = (slice(0, 64), slice(0, 64))


def pad_img(img):
    return np.pad(img, ((0, 2), (0, 17)), mode='constant')


def get_data(rotation=False, shifting=False, zooming=False):
    train_data = fetch_lfw_pairs(subset='train')
    test_data = fetch_lfw_pairs(subset='test')

    x1s_trn, x2s_trn, ys_trn, x1s_vld, x2s_vld = [], [], [], [], []

    for (pair, y) in zip(train_data.pairs, train_data.target):
        img1, img2 = pad_img(pair[0]), pad_img(pair[1])
        x1s_trn.append(img1)
        x2s_trn.append(img2)
        ys_trn.append(y)

        if rotation:
            for angle in ROTATIONS_RANGE:
                x1s_trn.append(np.asarray(rotate(img1, angle))[IMG_SLICE])
                x2s_trn.append(np.asarray(rotate(img2, angle))[IMG_SLICE])
                ys_trn.append(y)
                x1s_trn.append(np.asarray(rotate(img1, -angle))[IMG_SLICE])
                x2s_trn.append(np.asarray(rotate(img2, -angle))[IMG_SLICE])
                ys_trn.append(y)

        if shifting:
            for pixels_to_shift in SHIFTS_RANGE:
                x1s_trn.append(shift(img1, pixels_to_shift))
                x2s_trn.append(shift(img2, pixels_to_shift))
                ys_trn.append(y)
                x1s_trn.append(shift(img1, -pixels_to_shift))
                x2s_trn.append(shift(img2, -pixels_to_shift))
                ys_trn.append(y)

        if zooming:
            for zm in ZOOM_RANGE:
                x1s_trn.append(np.asarray(zoom(img1, zm))[IMG_SLICE])
                x2s_trn.append(np.asarray(zoom(img2, zm))[IMG_SLICE])
                ys_trn.append(y)

    for (img1, img2) in test_data.pairs:
        x1s_vld.append(pad_img(img1))
        x2s_vld.append(pad_img(img2))

    return (
        np.array(x1s_trn),
        np.array(x2s_trn),
        np.array(ys_trn),
        np.array(x1s_vld),
        np.array(x2s_vld),
        np.array(test_data.target)
    )
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Have you tried ensembling?

Comment: You can't expect a good generalization with too few data. The very first thing to do is to gather as much data as you can. Basically, how many data do you have ? And how many labels ?

Comment: @cprakashagr no, but shouldn't dropout give the same effect?

Comment: @debzsud I have 2200 training image pairs (this is artificially augmented to ~50000 using rotation, shifting, zooming each image pair with different parameters) and 1000 validation pairs. I have only 2 labels, 1 - both images display the same person, 0 - images display different persons.

Comment: It looks like you're only putting dropout on the back end of the network - have you tried putting dropout on the convolutional layers as well?  I'd try that before bothering too much with L1/L2 regularization.  If this is a binary classification problem, you probably also want a sigmoid in the output (logit activation for binary classifier to yield prediction on [0,1]

Comment: Your second maxpooling layer is also down-sampling really aggressively (strides=4)... this is atypical and may be throwing away too much information.  Try using 2x2 and strides=2 on this layer as well.  Additionally, your first convolutional layer only has 15 filters for a large (7x7) convolutional kernel which is likely far too few for so large a conv. kernel - you might try increasing the number of filters here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common problem with small size dataset (LFW dataset size = 13,000 images).

you can try:

- Transfer learning: https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/08_Transfer_Learning.ipynb
- Use larger dataset (= 202599 images): http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/CelebA.html

Comment: I use LFW pairs data from sklearn (2200 training images / 1000 test images), so yeah, it can be a problem. But as I mentioned, data augmentation techniques do not help. But I'll try, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Usually data augmentation is not so useful in this case, specially for face verification task, you need some per-trained convolution layers. You can achieve that by unsupervised training on large dataset, or by transfer learning.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use batch normalization instead of dropout. Or even both (though some weird things usually happen when using both).

Or as @Abdu307 proposes, use pretrained layers. You can train the model with a huge general dataset and later on do some fine-tuning with your face dataset.